# Players can see each other on different scenes in the same room

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm looking for a method to change a scene with Photon Engine. The issue is:

1. Players are joined to the room and can see each other... Player A and Player B.
2. Then, if a Player A goes to another scene with PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel() Player B still can see him at the same scene
3. If a Player B goes to another scene to Player A they **can't see each other**, even when they are back to initial scene

I have tried:

**Method for joining initial scene**

```
public override void OnJoinedRoom()
{
   PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel();
}
```

**Method for changing a scene for one player**

```
if (other.GetComponent<PhotonView>().IsMine)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            {
                PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel();
                DontDestroyOnLoad(other);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's correct. Different scenes does mean different rooms. You can a fastly completely different scene but than another player but still see the player. Remember a scene is handled locally. You might want to change Rooms of the players. Have a set number of rooms for each scene and then transfer htem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I can create several rooms but player gets destroyed, is there any other way to use DontDestroyOnLoad with Photon Engine and transfer player game object to another room to another level?

Comment: @CorrieJanse also should I use AutomaticallySyncScene = true???